What does GitLab actually do under the hood while creating a merge commit?
I'm trying to understand how GitLab makes merge commit. Pure git has different behaviour and it's not so clear why merge commits are required in GitLab
Let's say we have empty repository and perform first commit named direct commit to branch. Then we create a branch b-4 with two commits. Let's merge b-4 branch into main.
Note: keep in mind we use Merge commit method with squash option. Read more at Merge methods.
After merge is done we see the following history in GitLab web-interface (not a screenshot, sorry):
Merge branch 'b-4' into 'main'  d08bf37f
Squashed commit                 ebc509c2
direct commit to branch         34b29e2b

I expect to see something like that in git tree when I run git log --graph --decorate command:
*   commit d08bf37ff7157d48354c001ac066a6a44aece33e (HEAD -> main, origin/main)
|   Author: author_name <author_name@example.com>
|   Date:   Fri Jun 14 16:30:27 2024 +0300
|  
|       Merge branch 'b-4' into 'main'
|  
|       Squashed commit
|  
|       See merge request author_name/repo_name!1
|  
*   commit ebc509c25c945b63fbc3f387bb308a54b1006e90
|   Author: author_name <author_name@example.com>
|   Date:   Fri Jun 14 16:30:27 2024 +0300
|
|       Squashed commit
|
*   commit 34b29e2b89d38439299feef0ac64b926ba9d5d38
    Author: author_name <author_name@example.com>
    Date:   Fri Jun 14 16:29:09 2024 +0300
   
        direct commit to branch

But actually I observe the following:
*   commit d08bf37ff7157d48354c001ac066a6a44aece33e (HEAD -> main, origin/main)
|\  Merge: 34b29e2 ebc509c
| | Author: author_name <author_name@example.com>
| | Date:   Fri Jun 14 16:30:27 2024 +0300
| |
| |     Merge branch 'b-4' into 'main'
| |
| |     Squashed commit
| |
| |     See merge request author_name/repo_name!1
| |
| * commit ebc509c25c945b63fbc3f387bb308a54b1006e90
|/  Author: author_name <author_name@example.com>
|   Date:   Fri Jun 14 16:30:27 2024 +0300
|
|       Squashed commit
|
*   commit 34b29e2b89d38439299feef0ac64b926ba9d5d38
    Author: author_name <author_name@example.com>
    Date:   Fri Jun 14 16:29:09 2024 +0300
   
        direct commit to branch


Why is the tree not linear?
Why does the top level merge commit have Merge: 34b29e2 ebc509c line?
What does actually happen at low level?
How to reproduce that behaviour using pure git?

Article How does GitLab merge request with squash work under the hood? doesn't answer my question.

If you want linear history you should choose rebase, not a merge commit

"squash" AND "merge commit"?

But from your history graph, it looks like it is doing the equivalent of first doing a git reset --soft "$(git merge-base "$target" "$branch")", followed by git commit -m "$message" and eventually a regular git checkout "$target" && git merge --no-ff "$branch".

Creating a squash commit, and then another merge commit, barely makes sense, because the merge commit adds no informational value to the resulting graph. One possible way it does make sense though is for continuity with having the Merge Commit contain the MR number and branch names information, and presumably this is why GitLab offers this option.
In order for this to work, the merge commit, by definition, must have two parents. So the actual graph that you see in your repository is correct. I suspect the only reason you expected to see a linear graph is because the GitLab documentation is currently wrong. In this image the right most commit cannot be a merge commit:

I assume if someone notifies GitLab of the error they will fix it so that the resulting image would show the merge commit with two parents, E and the squash commit. While they're fixing that, they might as well fix the sentence to clearly state this is the Merge commit option, combined with Squash commit.
Regarding how the squash and merge commit works behind the scenes, it's probably something like this:
# create a temp branch called feature-squash starting from main:
git switch -c feature-squash main

# Begin squash merge of the feature branch:
git merge feature --squash

# Complete squash merge of the feature branch
git commit -m "Squash feature branch into a single commit"

# Checkout main:
git switch main

# Force a merge commit on main for the squashed commit:
git merge feature-squash --no-ff -m "Force merge commit for Squash Merge"

Side Note: When squashing, you could choose the alternative method of Squash Merge, and then you simply get the single linear squashed commit, without the extra (unnecessary except maybe commit message meta-data) merge commit along with it. However, when you are not squashing and you have more than 1 commit, I personally recommend always forcing a merge commit even if fast-forward is possible, so that the entire history of that feature can be  discerned from the commit history.

Squashing pull requests is always wrong and should be done.

@hlovdal I generally agree with that, and I typically don't allow it in repos under my control. My preference is for the developers to squash their own branches themselves if they want to. The person who learns how to do it on their own becomes the person who can clean up their branch and create (potentially multiple,) useful commits.

To replicate the merge behavior locally with Git, use the --no-ff option, which stands for non fast-forward.
# selecting the main branch
git checkout main

# merging b-4 into main and creating a merge commit
git merge --no-ff b-4

Like so, the given commits are always merged together creating a merge commit, even for cases that would be resolved with a fast-forward.

With --no-ff, create a merge commit in all cases, even when the merge could instead be resolved as a fast-forward.


GitHub has different behaviour, much simpler

Finally I managed to reproduce GitLab 'Merge commit + squash' behaviour. According to @knittl comment git reset --soft did the trick.
export branch=b-3

# switch to branch and fill it with fake data
git checkout -b ${branch}
echo $(date) >> data.txt
git add data.txt
git commit -am "data commit number 1"
echo $(date) >> data.txt
git commit -am "data commit number 2"

# compact all commits in branch into single one
git reset --soft "$(git merge-base main ${branch})"
git commit -am "squashed commit"

# go to main branch and perform a merge with no fast-forward option
git checkout main
git merge --no-ff ${branch}

# optional: remove branch
git branch -d ${branch}

Then you'll se the following git tree running git log --graph --decorate --all:
*   commit 4de3015a0cea2a95592c6e2e7dd8ba750cb88627 (HEAD -> main)
|\  Merge: 86e6ea0 360ca0b
| | Author: author_name <author_name@example.com>
| | Date:   Mon Jun 17 22:31:03 2024 +0300
| |
| |     Merge branch 'b-3'
| |
| * commit 360ca0b842d0148485f4589aa734e6b6fe145be7
|/  Author: author_name <author_name@example.com>
|   Date:   Mon Jun 17 22:30:52 2024 +0300
|
|       squashed commits
|
* commit 86e6ea0f8cdd7788261d48c60a15dd87c0bb4806
  Author: author_name <author_name@example.com>
  Date:   Mon Jun 17 22:29:54 2024 +0300
 
      initial commit to main

By the way, according to @TTT answer about 'Merge commit' feature sense - 'entire history of that feature can be discerned from the commit history'. I partially agree but nowadays we have more convenient ways to add additional data about PR into commits. I mean Autolinked references in GitHub or Cross-references in GitLab.
Anyway, thank you guys for your answers

The 8 Types of Merge in Git
There are 8 ways to merge commits in Git, depending on whether the merge is resolved as a fast-forward or not, commits are squashed or not, and commits are rebased or not.
Example:
* 02cdce4 (x) d
* 7feb434 c
| * 831cb8f (y) e
|/
* f059d83 (HEAD -> main) b
* bbd88d8 a

git init
touch a
git add .
git commit -m a
touch b
git add .
git commit -m b
git switch -c x
touch c
git add .
git commit -m c
touch d
git add .
git commit -m d
git switch main
git switch -c y
touch e
git add .
git commit -m e
git switch main
git log --all --graph --oneline

We are going to apply the 8 types of merge on this commit history with Git to merge branches x and y into branch main, and show the resulting commit history. The user interfaces of GitHub and GitLab allow only 3 and 6 of those types of merge, respectively.
Fast-forward, squash, rebase

Git:
git merge --squash <source-branch>
git commit


GitHub: Squash and merge.

GitLab: Fast-forward merge and Squash commits.


Example:
* f952eb6 (HEAD -> main) e
* 89f7a22 cd
| * 02cdce4 (x) d
| * 7feb434 c
|/
| * 831cb8f (y) e
|/
* f059d83 b
* bbd88d8 a

git merge --squash x
git commit -m cd
git merge --squash y
git commit -m e
git log --all --graph --oneline

Fast-forward, squash, no rebase

Git:
git switch --detach <source-branch>
git reset --soft $(git merge-base <source-branch> <target-branch>)
git commit
git switch <target-branch>
git merge -


GitHub: no equivalent.

GitLab: no equivalent.


Example:
*   50494f1 (HEAD -> main) e
|\
| * c6f5e15 e
* | e03556a cd
|/
| * 02cdce4 (x) d
| * 7feb434 c
|/
| * 831cb8f (y) e
|/
* f059d83 b
* bbd88d8 a

git switch --detach x
git reset --soft $(git merge-base x main)
git commit -m cd
git switch main
git merge -
git switch --detach y
git reset --soft $(git merge-base y main)
git commit -m e
git switch main
git merge -m e -
git log --all --graph --oneline

Fast-forward, no squash, rebase

Git:
git switch --detach <source-branch>
git rebase <target-branch>
git switch <target-branch>
git merge -


GitHub: Rebase and merge.

GitLab: Fast-forward merge and not Squash commits.


Example:
* 5d0d820 (HEAD -> main) e
* 02cdce4 (x) d
* 7feb434 c
| * 831cb8f (y) e
|/
* f059d83 b
* bbd88d8 a

git switch --detach x
git rebase main
git switch main
git merge -
git switch --detach y
git rebase main
git switch main
git merge -
git log --all --graph --oneline

Fast-forward, no squash, no rebase

Git:
git merge <source-branch>


GitHub: no equivalent.

GitLab: no equivalent.


Example:
*   652b5ea (HEAD -> main) e
|\
| * 831cb8f (y) e
* | 02cdce4 (x) d
* | 7feb434 c
|/
* f059d83 b
* bbd88d8 a

git merge x
git merge -m e y
git log --all --graph --oneline

No fast-forward, squash, rebase

Git:
git switch --detach <source-branch>
git reset --soft $(git merge-base <source-branch> <target-branch>)
git commit
git rebase <target-branch>
git switch <target-branch>
git merge --no-ff -


GitHub: no equivalent.

GitLab: Merge commit with semi-linear history and Squash commits.


Example:
*   ab290b4 (HEAD -> main) e
|\
| * 5c84150 e
|/
*   3f3103d cd
|\
| * f18ef11 cd
|/
| * 02cdce4 (x) d
| * 7feb434 c
|/
| * 831cb8f (y) e
|/
* f059d83 b
* bbd88d8 a

git switch --detach x
git reset --soft $(git merge-base x main)
git commit -m cd
git rebase main
git switch main
git merge --no-ff -m cd -
git switch --detach y
git reset --soft $(git merge-base y main)
git commit -m e
git rebase main
git switch main
git merge --no-ff -m e -
git log --all --graph --oneline

No fast-forward, squash, no rebase

Git:
git switch --detach <source-branch>
git reset --soft $(git merge-base <source-branch> <target-branch>)
git commit
git switch <target-branch>
git merge --no-ff -


GitHub: no equivalent.

GitLab: Merge commit and Squash commits.


Example:
*   20f4850 (HEAD -> main) e
|\
| * dd4fa26 e
* |   03c433a cd
|\ \
| |/
|/|
| * e346fae cd
|/
| * 02cdce4 (x) d
| * 7feb434 c
|/
| * 831cb8f (y) e
|/
* f059d83 b
* bbd88d8 a

git switch --detach x
git reset --soft $(git merge-base x main)
git commit -m cd
git switch main
git merge --no-ff -m cd -
git switch --detach y
git reset --soft $(git merge-base y main)
git commit -m e
git switch main
git merge --no-ff -m e -
git log --all --graph --oneline

No fast-forward, no squash, rebase

Git:
git switch --detach <source-branch>
git rebase <target-branch>
git switch <target-branch>
git merge --no-ff -


GitHub: no equivalent.

GitLab: Merge commit with semi-linear history and not Squash commits.


Example:
*   7fbb181 (HEAD -> main) e
|\
| * f08b115 e
|/
*   9507de7 cd
|\
| * 02cdce4 (x) d
| * 7feb434 c
|/
| * 831cb8f (y) e
|/
* f059d83 b
* bbd88d8 a

git switch --detach x
git rebase main
git switch main
git merge --no-ff -m cd -
git switch --detach y
git rebase main
git switch main
git merge --no-ff -m e -
git log --all --graph --oneline

No fast-forward, no squash, no rebase

Git:
git merge --no-ff <source-branch>


GitHub: Create a merge commit.

GitLab: Merge commit and not Squash commits.


Example:
*   f8e2764 (HEAD -> main) e
|\
| * 831cb8f (y) e
* |   99929b7 cd
|\ \
| |/
|/|
| * 02cdce4 (x) d
| * 7feb434 c
|/
* f059d83 b
* bbd88d8 a

git merge --no-ff -m cd x
git merge --no-ff -m e y
git log --all --graph --oneline

